# add method to custom object to use it in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, standardcontroller, method

i have a custom object called `File_Uploaded__c` and i have a `visual force page` which will generate details page for the file  based on its fields: here's the definition of my `visual force page`:

```
<apex:page standardController="File_Uploaded__c" >

</apex>
```

As you can see the controller for this page is the the `custom object` itself.

and the fields that i will use in this page are encoded in `JSON format`, so i need to define a method that transform all those fields to a normal format and then use them in my page, But the problem i don't know how to define method associated with my custom object.

Comment: Google "salesforce controller extension" and read.

Comment: and 2nd thing to read about is JSON serialization and de-serialization

Comment: @KeithC thanks for the answer. Can you give some good examples for this please

Comment: @ihssan You will find examples via Google.

Comment: the proble is that i need to pass a parameter to the extension method  which will be the field of my custom object, and i don't know how to do that

Comment: @ihssan A controller extension can directly reference the object loaded by the standard controller.

Comment: well thank you for the answer, i didn' know that, i am new in `apex` and `visual force pages` .

Comment: if you want you can post it as an answer so i can set it as the correct one

Comment: @KeithC only one question, how can i reference the object loaded by the standard controller in my extension ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add logic in a [controller extension](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm) and a controller extension can directly reference the object loaded by the standard controller:

```
public class MyControllerExtension {

    private final File_Uploaded__c fileUploaded;

    public MyControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.fileUploaded = (File_Uploaded__c) sc.getRecord();
    }

    private void someMethod() {
        ...
        fileUploaded.SomeField__c = 'xyz';
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: that's the last thing i need to know : how can i reference the object loaded by the standard controller  within my extension?

Comment: Added that. Please spend some time using e.g. Salesforce's workbooks to learn more before you post further questions.